# Elements with position sticky on table cells overlaps and z-index doesn't work

Tags: html, css, sticky

I have this table:

```css
.collapsible {
    --line-height: 40;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: calc(var(--line-height) * 6px);
    min-height: calc(var(--line-height) * 5px);
    max-height: calc(var(--rows) * (var(--line-height) + 1) * 1px);
}
.collapsible table {
    position: relative;
}
.level-2 [rowspan] {
    vertical-align: top;
}
table td,
table th {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.25px;
}
table td:not([rowspan]),
table [rowspan] div {
    padding: 8px 0 8px 8px;
}
table.new th:not([rowspan]) {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
table.new th:not([rowspan]) div {
    z-index: 100;
    background: white;
    height: calc(var(--line-height) * 1px);
}
table.new td:not([rowspan]),
table.new th:not([rowspan]) div,
table [rowspan] div {
    --padding: calc(1px * (var(--line-height) - 20) / 2);
    padding: var(--padding) 8px var(--padding) 8px;
}

.level-2 [rowspan] div {
    position: sticky;
    background: white;
    z-index: 0;
    top: calc(var(--line-height) * 1px);
}
```

```html
<div class="collapsible">
   <table class="new">
        <tr>
            <th><div>Project Stage</div></th>
            <th><div>Terapeutic Area</div></th>
            <th class="right"><div>Year</div></th>
            <th class="right"><div>Percentage Share</div></th>
            <th class="right"><div>Unit Share</div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2 agragated-2-row">
            <th rowspan="9" class="level-0"><div>DEV</div></th>
            <td rowspan="3"><div>Cancer Immunology</div></td>
            <td>2020</td>
            <td>4%</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2019</td>
            <td>1%</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2018</td>
            <td>2%</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2 agragated-1-row">
            <td rowspan="3"><div>Immunology</div></td>
            <td>2020</td>
            <td>4%</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2019</td>
            <td>1%</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2018</td>
            <td>2%</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2 agragated-1-row">
            <td rowspan="3"><div>Infectious Diseases</div></td>
            <td>2020</td>
            <td>4%</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2019</td>
            <td>1%</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2018</td>
            <td>2%</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2 agragated-2-row">
            <th rowspan="6" class="level-0"><div>ED</div></th>
            <td rowspan="3"><div>Cancer Immunology</div></td>
            <td>2020</td>
            <td>4%</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2019</td>
            <td>1%</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2018</td>
            <td>2%</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2 agragated-1-row">
            <td rowspan="3"><div>Immunology</div></td>
            <td>2020</td>
            <td>4%</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2019</td>
            <td>1%</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2018</td>
            <td>2%</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The problem is that table cells that are not in the header are above the header sticky cells when you scroll.

So in this CSS:

```css
/* this is for first row of th */
table.new th:not([rowspan]) div {
    position: sticky;
    background: white;
    z-index: 100;
}
/* this is for rowspan that is sticky, they are below first row */
.level-2 [rowspan] div {
    position: sticky;
    background: white;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

z-index is ignored. And when adding a negative z-index the cells disappear.

I've tried to put div:

```html
<th>
    <div>
        <div class="filler">
            Project Stage
        </div>
    </div>
</th>
```

and css

```css
.filler {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    background: white;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

But this doesn't work. The sticky element that is next is always on top of the previous sticky element in HTML. Is there a way to change the order of sticky elements?
I'm happy with any hack that makes this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set z-index "level-2 [rowspan] div" class with value -100 this will force this element to be sent back of all other elements

```
.level-2 [rowspan] div {
    position: sticky;
    background: white;
    z-index: -100;
    top: calc(var(--line-height) * 1px);
}
```

and after that, you will find that the header row needs a little adjustment to increase the height of "table.new th:not([rowspan]) div" class with 5 px

```
table.new th:not([rowspan]) div {
    z-index: 100;
    background: white;
    height: calc(5+ var(--line-height) * 1px);
}
```

this the full code snippet

```css
.collapsible {
    --line-height: 40;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: calc(var(--line-height) * 6px);
    min-height: calc(var(--line-height) * 5px);
    max-height: calc(var(--rows) * (var(--line-height) + 1) * 1px);
}
.collapsible table {
    position: relative;
}
.level-2 [rowspan] {
    vertical-align: top;
}
table td,
table th {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.25px;
}
table td:not([rowspan]),
table [rowspan] div {
    padding: 8px 0 8px 8px;
}
table.new th:not([rowspan]) {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
table.new th:not([rowspan]) div {
    z-index: 100;
    background: white;
    height: calc(5+ var(--line-height) * 1px);
}
table.new td:not([rowspan]),
table.new th:not([rowspan]) div,
table [rowspan] div {
    --padding: calc(1px * (var(--line-height) - 20) / 2);
    padding: var(--padding) 8px var(--padding) 8px;
}

.level-2 [rowspan] div {
    position: sticky;
    background: white;
    z-index: -100;
    top: calc(var(--line-height) * 1px);
}
```

```html
<div class="collapsible">
   <table class="new">
        <tr>
            <th><div>Project Stage</div></th>
            <th><div>Terapeutic Area</div></th>
            <th class="right"><div>Year</div></th>
            <th class="right"><div>Percentage Share</div></th>
            <th class="right"><div>Unit Share</div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2 agragated-2-row">
            <th rowspan="9" class="level-0"><div>DEV</div></th>
            <td rowspan="3"><div>Cancer Immunology</div></td>
            <td>2020</td>
            <td>4%</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2019</td>
            <td>1%</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2018</td>
            <td>2%</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2 agragated-1-row">
            <td rowspan="3"><div>Immunology</div></td>
            <td>2020</td>
            <td>4%</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2019</td>
            <td>1%</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2018</td>
            <td>2%</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2 agragated-1-row">
            <td rowspan="3"><div>Infectious Diseases</div></td>
            <td>2020</td>
            <td>4%</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2019</td>
            <td>1%</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2018</td>
            <td>2%</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2 agragated-2-row">
            <th rowspan="6" class="level-0"><div>ED</div></th>
            <td rowspan="3"><div>Cancer Immunology</div></td>
            <td>2020</td>
            <td>4%</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2019</td>
            <td>1%</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2018</td>
            <td>2%</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2 agragated-1-row">
            <td rowspan="3"><div>Immunology</div></td>
            <td>2020</td>
            <td>4%</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2019</td>
            <td>1%</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="level-2">
            <td>2018</td>
            <td>2%</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it would be nice if you describe what did you change. I was trying negative z-index but the cell was disappearing.

Comment: i encrease the height for table.new th:not([rowspan]) div by 5 to hide the background also in this class height: calc(5+ var(--line-height) * 1px);

Comment: But you should write this in the answer, not in the comment. Also, those changes don't matter much, the crucial is the z-index that I was trying but was not able to solve the issue. Maybe z-index in combination with background solved the issue because when I was using negative z-index the cell disappeared.

Comment: @MohamedHassan - best to describe what you did in the actual answer and not in the comments :)